# Store regex matches in ruby?

Tags: ruby, regex, match

I'm parsing a file with ruby to change the data formatting. I created a regex which has three match groups that I want to temporally store in variables. I'm having trouble getting the matches to be stored as everything is nil.

Here is what I have so far from what I've read.

```
regex = '^"(\bhttps?://[-\w+&@#/%?=~_|$!:,.;]*[\w+&@#/%=~_|$])","(\w+|[\w._%+-]+@[\w.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4})","(\w{1,30})'

begin
  file = File.new("testfile.csv", "r")
  while (line = file.gets)
    puts line
    match_array = line.scan(/regex/)
    puts $&
  end
  file.close
end
```

Here is some sample data that I'm using for testing.

```
"https://mail.google.com","Master","password1","","https://mail.google.com","",""
"https://login.sf.org","monster@gmail.com","password2","https://login.sf.org","","ctl00$ctl00$ctl00$body$body$wacCenterStage$standardLogin$tbxUsername","ctl00$ctl00$ctl00$body$body$wacCenterStage$standardLogin$tbxPassword"
"http://www.facebook.com","Beast","12345678","https://login.facebook.com","","email","pass"
"http://www.own3d.tv","Earth","passWOrd3","http://www.own3d.tv","","user_name","user_password"
```

Thank you,
LF4

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This won't work:

```
match_array = line.scan(/regex/)
```

That's just using a literal "regex" string as your regular expression, not what's in your `regex` variable. You can either put the big ugly regex right into your `scan` or create a Regexp instance:

```
regex = Regexp.new('^"(\bhttps?://[-\w+&@#/%?=~_|$!:,.;]*[\w+&@#/%=~_|$])","(\w+|[\w._%+-]+@[\w.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4})","(\w{1,30})')
# ...
match_array = line.scan(regex)
```

And you should probably use a CSV library (one comes with Ruby: [1.8.7](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.8.7/libdoc/csv/rdoc/index.html) or [1.9](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/csv/rdoc/index.html)) for parsing CSV files, then apply a regular expression to each column from the CSV. You'll run into fewer quoting and escaping issues that way.

Comment: Wow thank you. I'm surprised all the searching none of the sites mentioned or showed their examples having to use Regexp.new. That did it. Thanks again.

Comment: @LF4: I think you should use a CSV parser and 3 simpler regular expressions though. In any case, with regexes that complicated, putting them in a variable (of the right type of course) and referencing that variable in `scan` calls was the right move.

Comment: Yeah using the CSV parser was much easier. I don't know why I didn't think about looking into that instead of doing a regex. :) Thanks for all the help.

Comment: @LF4: When all you have is a hammer... Getting locked into the wrong approach and beating your head against the wall trying to make it work is standard human behavior, we all do it.